# Java. Задание занчения (final) переменной в try-блоке и ее дальнейшее использование и видимость

Tags: java, переменные, инициализация, try-catch

Проблема заключается в необходимости задания значения final переменной (connectionSocket2) в try-блоке. В дальнейшей части кода (в части `run()`) этого не видно и возникает как бы ошибка, что та переменная не определена:

```
        final Socket connectionSocket;
        try { connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept(); }
```

> The local variable connectionSocket2 may not have been initialized

убрать `final` не могу, так как (в части `run()`) дает ошибку

> Cannot refer to the non-final local variable connectionSocket defined
>   in an enclosing scope

```
            Socket connectionSocket2=null;
            try { connectionSocket2 = welcomeSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e2) { e2.printStackTrace(); }
            final Socket connectionSocket=connectionSocket2; try{connectionSocket2.close();}catch(IOException e1){e1.printStackTrace();}

            service.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        BufferedReader inFromClient=null;
                        DataOutputStream outToClient=null;
                        try{
                           inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
                           outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
                           outToClient.writeBytes(inFromClient.readLine());
                        } catch(IOException ioe) {} }}});
```

Статической делать не могу - для каждого потока создается свое соединение, как бы свой экземпляр этой переменной.

Приведенный код работает, использовал вторую переменную для передачи ей значения и дальнейшего использования именной второй переменной. Но это выглядит плохо.

Как правильно, профессионально быть в этой ситуации? Модно ли как-то сказать компилятору, что переменная на самом деле уже определена в try блоке и ему нечего "волноваться"? (типа динамическая переменная, как в .Net)

Comment: Код `connectionSocket2 = welcomeSocket.accept(); connectionSocket=connectionSocket2; connectionSocket2.close();` вызывает сомнения.

Comment: @zRrr
Правильно! потому и тему создал)) ...код этот работает, но в таком виде оставлять не допустимо. Хорошо бы с ран блок как в с++ ссылкой на указатель, или как в сшарп сделать динамической переменной или еще что-то, что бы компилятор понимал что переменная уже была определена в трай-блоке...

Comment: вы, по-моему, что-то странное придумали: если будет исключение при `welcomeSocket.accept()`, `connectionSocket2` останется равным `null`, и работа всего дальнейшего кода бессмысленна. Если исключения не будет, у вас `connectionSocket` и `connectionSocket2` будут ссылками на один объект, который вы закроете.

Comment: Почему не поместить все объявление Runnable в try-блок или не объявить его вообще отдельным классом с передачей параметра в конструктор?

Comment: @Etki
все в try-блок - слишком примитивно. try-блок работает медленнее. Отдельный класс в общем хорошо, но это дополнительные объекты, была бы ссылка на final переменную с заданным значением в try-блоке - все было бы компактно и хорошо.

Comment: Вы правда думаете, что new Runnable - это не дополнительные объекты? Вы правда думаете, что try затормозит ваше приложение?

Comment: @Etki
try замедляет программу, не на много, но при тысячах потоков - лучше свести try к минимуму. (пример - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255878/try-catch-performance-java). new Runnable - да, доп. обхекты, но они выделяются конкретно под задачу, и потом повторно используются, а вот в новом классе явной нужды нет в данном случае.

Comment: Вообще-то в примере сказано, что замедление произойдет при исключении (время будет потрачено на сбор трассы стека). Исключение у вас будет, когда отвалится слушающий сокет (ну либо вы сделали `setSoTimout`), т.е. весь код дальше просто не должен будет работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ-вопросник и очередной наброс на медальку.

Итак, у вас было что-то вот такое:

```
public class ICanIntoSockets {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(10000);
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        doWork( welcomeSocket, service );
    }

    public static void doWork( ServerSocket welcomeSocket, ExecutorService service ) {
        try {
            while (true) {
                final Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

                service.execute( () -> {
                    try (   Socket socket = connectionSocket;
                            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream())) {

                        outToClient.writeBytes(inFromClient.readLine());
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch ( IOException ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

но `try` - плохо, и [торморзит](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255878/try-catch-performance-java) на тысячах подключений (тесты где?), поэтому вы решили от него избавиться. Ява - убогий язык, в ней зачем-то придумали Checked Exceptions и напихали во все места в стандартной библиотеке, поэтому совсем без `try` - никак:

```
public static void doWork( ServerSocket welcomeSocket, ExecutorService service ) {
    while (true) {
        final Socket connectionSocket;
        try {
            connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        service.execute(() -> {
            try (   Socket socket = connectionSocket; // The local variable connectionSocket may not have been initialized
                    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {

                outToClient.writeBytes(inFromClient.readLine());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Зло загнано в угол в одной строчке кода! Но компилятор почему-то считает, что переменная `connectionSocket` *может быть* не инициализирована. Почему? Потому что есть путь выполнения программы, при которой она действительно не инициализируется: когда `welcomeSocket.accept()` выбрасывает исключение. Метод не возвращает значение - значение переменной не присваивается. Что же делать?

Не надо продолжать выполнение итерации, ваш код все равно не сможет работать дальше без клиентского сокета. Сделайте внутри `catch`-блока `return`, `break`, `continue` (в надежде, что следующий `accept` не выбросит исключение, что вряд ли). Если код непременно должен продолжаться дальше - присвойте `connectionSocket` `null` и где-то сделайте проверку.

Предложенный вариант с массивом - это либо то самое создание объектов и выделение памяти, с которым вы сражаетесь, либо потеря подключений и обработка одного подключения несколько раз, смотря где вы этот массив объявите.

Comment: Ого!)) Выглядит очень хорошо! Спасибо!!
Осталось переписать -> на java7 и проверить код.

Answer (score 5):

Можно обёртку сделать:

```
public class MySocket{
    private Socket  mSocket;
    public MySocket(){
    }

    public void setSocket(Socket socket){
        mSocket = socket;
    }

    public Socket getSocket(){
        return mSocket;
    }
}
```

И создать его экземпляр:

```
final MySocket connectionSocket = new MySocket();
```

И дальше:

```
try{ 
       connectionSocket.setSocket(welcomeSocket.accept());    
   } catch (IOException e2) { 
       e2.printStackTrace(); 
   }
```

И внутри `Runnable` обращаться к `connectionSocket.getSocket()`.

Comment: Спасибо! Выглядит хорошо, но не многовато ли объектов создается? Кроме доп. объекта сокета, еще и класс... Если бы сделать без создания чего-то дополнительного, как в с++ обратиться указателем на уже инициализированный объект с ран-блока, или какое-то типа @SuppressError на ошибку инициализации, когда была сделана в трай-блоке...

Comment: @CodeGust это то, что пришло сходу в голову. Может и есть красивее решение, но я слишком устал сегодня, чтоб что-то другое посоветовать, сорри =/

Answer (score 1):

создайте final Socket[] на один элемент и в пишите в него.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!! Просто и эффективно!
(но, все же, интересно бы найти способ сказать компилятору, что final переменная была определена в try блоке... )

Comment: На 3-4 раз запуска проекта выдает Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException на строку `try { connectionSocket[0] = welcomeSocket.accept();}`

Comment: Не очень понятно, что до этого происходит в вашей программе, но исходя из этой строки, проблема в том, что вы вызываете accept() на welcomeSocket, который иногда почему-то null.